# Overwrite node's option in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, foreach

I'm using `\foreach` in order to simplify the task of manually setting nodes with a certain style, but I'd like to change some of the nodes' options afterwards.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfset{
  foreach/parallel foreach/.style args={#1in#2via#3}{evaluate=#3 as #1 using {{#2}[#3-1]}},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick, scale=2.5,
x={({cos(-20)},{-sin(-20)},0)},z={({-sin(-35)},{-cos(-35)},0)}]
\def\y{0.5}
\def\vertecislist{{0,0,1},{1,0,1},{2,0,1},{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{2,0,0},{0,\y,1},{1,\y,1},{2,\y,1},{0,\y,0},{1,\y,0},{2,\y,0}}
\def\nodeslist{1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 12, 7, 14, 28, 21, 42, 84}
\foreach \pos [count=\Ind,
  parallel foreach=\l in \nodeslist via \Ind]
  in \vertecislist
  {
    \node[circle,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt,fill=black,
        label=\ifnum\Ind<7 below\else above\fi:\l](p\l) at (\pos){};
  }
  
  \draw (p84)edge(p12)edge(p28)--(p42)edge(p6)edge(p14)--
      (p21)edge(p7)--(p3)edge(p6)--(p1)edge(p2)--
      (p7)--(p14)edge(p28)--(p2)edge(p6)--(p4)edge(p28)--(p12)--(p6);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This way doesn't seem to work:

```
\draw (p84) node[label=90:$84$]{} edge(p12)edge(p28)--(p42)node[fill=red]{}edge(p6)edge(p14)--
      (p21)edge(p7)--(p3)edge(p6)--(p1)edge(p2)--
      (p7)--(p14)edge(p28)node[fill=red]{}--(p2)edge(p6)--(p4)edge(p28)--(p12)--(p6);
```

Is there a way of changing any of `(p#)` after it's been defined? I need to change `(p28)` fill color and the label angle of `(p84)`.

Comment: TikZ has not been done to change settings after "drawing". See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Once you drew a node, you can't undraw it, so your only solution is to draw on it.

[image: nodes on parallelepiped]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{rnode/.style={circle,red,fill=red,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=2pt}}

\pgfset{
  foreach/parallel foreach/.style args={#1in#2via#3}{evaluate=#3 as #1 using {{#2}[#3-1]}},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick, scale=2.5,
x={({cos(-20)},{-sin(-20)},0)},z={({-sin(-35)},{-cos(-35)},0)}]
\def\y{0.5}
\def\vertecislist{{0,0,1},{1,0,1},{2,0,1},{0,0,0},{1,0,0},{2,0,0},{0,\y,1},{1,\y,1},{2,\y,1},{0,\y,0},{1,\y,0},{2,\y,0}}
\def\nodeslist{1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 12, 7, 14, 28, 21, 42, 84}
\foreach \pos [count=\Ind,
  parallel foreach=\l in \nodeslist via \Ind]
  in \vertecislist
  {
    \node[circle,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt,fill=black,
        label=\ifnum\Ind<7 below\else above\fi:\l](p\l) at (\pos){};
  }
  
  \draw (p84)edge(p12)edge(p28)--(p42)edge(p6)edge(p14)--(p21)edge(p7)--(p3)edge(p6)--(p1)edge(p2)--(p7)--(p14)edge(p28)--(p2)edge(p6)--(p4)edge(p28)--(p12)--(p6);
      
   \path (p28) node[rnode]{} -- (p42) node[rnode]{};
   \path (p84) node[above=3pt,circle,fill=white,inner sep=5pt]{} node[above right]{84};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```